# Test out parameters with Nunit in a single statement

Tags: c#, nunit

Is it possible to test the return value and `out` parametes with the same assert?
Im looking for something like this:

```
Assert.That(int.TryParse("1", out var number), Is.True.And(// check for number == 1));
```

Comment: Head => Table. Sure! There is still the classic model. I totally forgot about that. Thanks @PrasadTelkikar! Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to? The code will look convoluted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
Assert.IsTrue(int.TryParse("1", out var number) && number == 1);
```

POC: [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rTzdqt)

** without Assert, just to check condition

Comment: I removed the `== true` because its kinda redundant, but thanks a lot for the idea.